# Substituting Pandas Shift Function

Tags: python, pandas

For what I need to accomplish, the Pandas Shift function works great.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe-shift/

But, if you didn't have access to the Pandas module, what are some other ways that you would access the row above or below some value?

I feel like there is a simple way to do this without modules but, I am not able to accomplish it.

Comment: In that case what will be your data type? List? numpy array? you can use `from scipy.ndimage.interpolation import shift` if it is numpy. You can use `from collections import deque` if it is a list

Comment: This data type would be a list.

Comment: You can use list indices, enumeration, iterating multiple slices at once, etc. If you want a specific answer, please ask a specific question with a [mcve] that has some sample input, code for what you've tried so far. and expected output

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll check both of these out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you could use `zip()` to get current and previous value on the same line:

```
xs = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
for curr, prev in zip(xs[1:], xs):
    print(curr, prev)

20 10
30 20
40 30
50 40
```

`zip()` terminates when the shorter list is exhausted.